# Convert a binary file with integers to its ascii representation

Tags: c, ascii

I have a binary file including integers that represents an ascii file. For example a file containing `hello` has a value of (using xxd)

```
0000000: 4800 0000 6500 0000 6c00 0000 6c00 0000  H...e...l...l...
0000010: 6f00 0000 0000 0000                      o.......
```

How can i read the file and convert it to the ascii string `Hello`?

**Edit** An example that shows exactly what i do and what i get. Just compile and run it. Put a file named "test.txt inside the pwd thats the plaintext message. The result are 2 files test.enc and test.dec. I know it is unsecure at all but i want to create this anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ACCURACY 5
#define SINGLE_MAX 100000
#define EXPONENT_MAX 10000
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define DEBUG 0

int modpow(long long a, long long b, int c) {
    int res = 1;
    while(b > 0) {
        /* Need long multiplication else this will overflow... */
        if(b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % c;
        }
        b = b >> 1;
        a = (a * a) % c; /* Same deal here */
    }
    return res;
}

int jacobi(int a, int n) {
    int twos, temp;
    int mult = 1;
    while(a > 1 && a != n) {
        a = a % n;
        if(a <= 1 || a == n) break;
        twos = 0;
        while(a % 2 == 0 && ++twos) a /= 2; /* Factor out multiples of 2 */
        if(twos > 0 && twos % 2 == 1) mult *= (n % 8 == 1 || n % 8 == 7) * 2 - 1;
        if(a <= 1 || a == n) break;
        if(n % 4 != 1 && a % 4 != 1) mult *= -1; /* Coefficient for flipping */
        temp = a;
        a = n;
        n = temp;
    }
    if(a == 0) return 0;
    else if(a == 1) return mult;
    else return 0; /* a == n => gcd(a, n) != 1 */
}

int solovayPrime(int a, int n) {
    int x = jacobi(a, n);
    if(x == -1) x = n - 1;
    return x != 0 && modpow(a, (n - 1)/2, n) == x;
}

int probablePrime(int n, int k) {
    if(n == 2) return 1;
    else if(n % 2 == 0 || n == 1) return 0;
    while(k-- > 0) {
        if(!solovayPrime(rand() % (n - 2) + 2, n)) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int randPrime(int n) {
    int prime = rand() % n;
    n += n % 2; /* n needs to be even so modulo wrapping preserves oddness */
    prime += 1 - prime % 2;
    while(1) {
        if(probablePrime(prime, ACCURACY)) return prime;
        prime = (prime + 2) % n;
    }
}

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    int temp;
    while(b != 0) {
        temp = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

int randExponent(int phi, int n) {
    int e = rand() % n;
    while(1) {
        if(gcd(e, phi) == 1) return e;
        e = (e + 1) % n;
        if(e <= 2) e = 3;
    }
}

int inverse(int n, int modulus) {
    int a = n, b = modulus;
    int x = 0, y = 1, x0 = 1, y0 = 0, q, temp;
    while(b != 0) {
        q = a / b;
        temp = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
        temp = x; x = x0 - q * x; x0 = temp;
        temp = y; y = y0 - q * y; y0 = temp;
    }
    if(x0 < 0) x0 += modulus;
    return x0;
}

int readFile(FILE* fd, char** buffer, int bytes) {
    int len = 0, cap = BUF_SIZE, r;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    *buffer = malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    while((r = fread(buf, sizeof(char), BUF_SIZE, fd)) > 0) {
        if(len + r >= cap) {
            cap *= 2;
            *buffer = realloc(*buffer, cap);
        }
        memcpy(&(*buffer)[len], buf, r);
        len += r;
    }
    /* Pad the last block with zeros to signal end of cryptogram. An additional block is added if there is no room */
    if(len + bytes - len % bytes > cap) *buffer = realloc(*buffer, len + bytes - len % bytes);
    do {
        (*buffer)[len] = '\0';
        len++;
    }
    while(len % bytes != 0);
    return len;
}

int encode(int m, int e, int n) {
    return modpow(m, e, n);
}

int decode(int c, int d, int n) {
    return modpow(c, d, n);
}

int* encodeMessage(int len, int bytes, char* message, int exponent, int modulus) {
    int *encoded = malloc((len/bytes) * sizeof(int));
    int x, i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i += bytes) {
        x = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < bytes; j++) x += message[i + j] * (1 << (7 * j));
        encoded[i/bytes] = encode(x, exponent, modulus);
        if(DEBUG) printf("%d ", encoded[i/bytes]);
    }
    return encoded;
}

int* decodeMessage(int len, int bytes, int* cryptogram, int exponent, int modulus) {
    int *decoded = malloc(len * bytes * sizeof(int));
    int x, i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        x = decode(cryptogram[i], exponent, modulus);
        for(j = 0; j < bytes; j++) {
            decoded[i*bytes + j] = (x >> (7 * j)) % 128;
            if(DEBUG) if(decoded[i*bytes + j] != '\0') printf("%c", decoded[i*bytes + j]);
        }
    }
    return decoded;
}       

int main(void) {

    int p, q, n, phi, e, d;
    int len;
    int bytes = 1;
    int *encoded, *decoded;
    char *buffer;
    FILE *f;
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(1) {

        p = randPrime(SINGLE_MAX);              
        q = randPrime(SINGLE_MAX);      
        n = p * q;
        if(n < 128) {
            printf("Modulus is less than 128, trying again\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }   

    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
    e = randExponent(phi, EXPONENT_MAX);    
    d = inverse(e, phi);

    // read the file
    f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(f == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    len = readFile(f, &buffer, bytes); // len will be a multiple of bytes, to send whole chunks 
    fclose(f);

    if(DEBUG) printf("Encoded: ");
    encoded = encodeMessage(len, bytes, buffer, e, n);

    // save the encoded binary! to file
    FILE *encodedFile;
    encodedFile = fopen("tmp.enc", "wb");
    fwrite(encoded, sizeof(int), len, encodedFile);
    fclose(encodedFile);

    // read the encodedFile binary! overwrite encoded!!!
    FILE *newEncodedFile;
    newEncodedFile = fopen("tmp.enc", "rb");
    fread(encoded, sizeof(int), len, newEncodedFile);
    fclose(newEncodedFile);

    if(DEBUG) printf("\nDecoded: ");
    decoded = decodeMessage(len/bytes, bytes, encoded, d, n);

    // save the decoded binary! to file
    FILE *decodedFile;
    decodedFile = fopen("tmp.dec", "wb");
    fwrite(decoded, sizeof(int), len/bytes, decodedFile);
    fclose(decodedFile);

    free(encoded);
    free(decoded);
    free(buffer);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That looks like UTF-32, not ASCII

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question.

Comment: So.. it looks like a text file in UTF32 encoding. No conversion is needed.. Unless you want to convert it to ASCII. But that would simply taking every 4th byte starting with the first one..

Comment: The key here is to open the file and use the proper encoding to decode it.

Comment: But the result is `H   e   l   l   o` when i open the file (3 whitespaces between every character).

Comment: Show the code that you are using to open and read the file. Most likely you are not decoding it with the correct encoding.

Comment: You can "open" a file in zillion of ways. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Read an `int` at a time, copy the value into a `char` then write the `char`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i am writing to a file and open it with notepad. I also use PSPad for encoding.

Comment: The code where i write the file is `fwrite(decoded, sizeof(int), len, decodedFile);` and file is open in `wb` mode

Comment: You better show your code in a form of [mcve].

Comment: What is the reason you are writing the file in binary mode rather than text mode?

Comment: because it will get encrypted so i need an exponent>128

Answer (score 1):

Characters are just integers that are displayed according to some arbitrary rules. Because the rules are arbitrary there are infinite possibilities. Of those infinite possibilities there are multiple standards (EBDIC, ASCII, many variations of "extended ASCII", Unicode, etc) and because they're all just integers there's many ways to encode them ("as is", UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, ..).

To convert from anything to anything, you need to decode the original encoding (if any), convert the resulting character into the new character set (possibly via. lookup tables), then re-encode the character in the target encoding (if any).

The data you've shown looks like "Unicode with UTF-32LE encoding". To convert it to "ASCII with as-is encoding" (in a portable way) you'd need to start by decoding the original encoding (e.g. `codepoint = buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << 8)  | (buffer[2] << 16) | (buffer[3] << 24)`). Then you'd need to convert the resulting codepoint ("character") into the ASCII character set. Fortunately, the first 128 codepoints in Unicode are identical to ASCII. Unfortunately almost all of the other codepoints in Unicode can't be converted to ASCII, so you'll need to decide what to do about that (replace them with a `'?'` character in ASCII? Generate a "Can't convert" error message and give up?). In any case it'll probably look something like `if(codepoint < 128) { character = codepoint; } else {`. Finally, because ASCII uses an "as is" encoding you can just slap the resulting byte into memory (there's no work involved in "re-encode").

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but something like this:

```
int utf32le2ascii(uint32_t *instr, size_t len, char *outstr, size_t outlen)
{
    size_t i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (j >= outlen)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (instr[i] < 128)
        {
            outstr[j] = instr[i];
        }

        else
        {
            outstr[j] = '?'; 
        }

        j++;
    }
    if (j >= outlen)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    outstr[j] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

A return value of `-1` indicates failure; `0` indicates success.